# Multiple type signatures for members, Union Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

If I have a property that might be a string or a boolean how do I define it:

```
interface Foo{
    bar:string;
    bar:boolean;
}
```

I don't want to resort to:

```
interface Foo{
    bar:any;
}
```

I don't think its possible without `any`. You can answer any of these:

Have I overlooked a spec and its possible right now? Is something like this planned? Has a feature request been logged?

I would imagine something like this:

```
interface Foo{
    bar:string;
    bar:boolean;
    bar:any; 
}

var x:Foo = <any>{};
x.bar="asdf";
x.bar.toUpperCase(); // intellisence only for string
```

Comment: Not sure of your usage scenario but would generics help you here?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is usually referred to as "union types". The TypeScript type system from 1.4 does allow for this.

See: [Advanced Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: Its allowed in functions [try it](http://goo.gl/M4qegd) I still (naively) think it can be allowed in properties. But you did answer my question. Btw. Its great to have a ts team member on stackoverflow, thanks for that. PS: my biggest concern is the slow compile, I die slowly every time it takes 5 seconds for me to see my code in action :)

Answer (score 207):

As of 2015, union-types work:

```
interface Foo {
    bar:string|boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Not saying this answers your question, but could you resort to something like this?

```
interface Foo<T>{
    bar:T;
}

function createFoo<T>(bar:T) : Foo<T>{
    return {bar:bar};
}

var sFoo = createFoo("s");
var len = sFoo.bar.length;

var bFoo = createFoo(true);
var result = bFoo.bar === true;
```

Comment: +1 for a useful answer. However my usage scenario is defining typescript interfaces for things like: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionsevent Currently I (and others) resort to `any` for such cases

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```
interface Base<T, T2> {
  a: T;
  b: T2;
}

type FirstExtendedBase = Base<boolean, string>;

const exampleOne: FirstExtendedBase = {
  a: false,
  b: '',
};

type SecondExtendedBase = Base<number, Date>;

const exampleTwo: SecondExtendedBase = {
  a: 42,
  b: new Date(),
};
```