# declare the property name with 2 types using OR notation doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

This solution doesn't work for me. Why? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35497353/1077309

Can I declare the property name with 2 types using OR notation like so?

```
export interface OnboardingSchoolModel {

    level?: string | number;
    school?: string;

}
```

I have tried that but it is not working. Any workaround for this?

I would like to limit the types for the property instead of giving `any`.

Compile-time error:

```
(property) OnboardingSchoolModel.level?: string | number
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

***Usage:***

```
  getSchools(): Promise<OnboardingSchoolModel[]> {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.onboardingService.getSchools().pipe(first()).subscribe((schools: any) => {
    const schoolList: OnboardingSchoolModel[] = [];
    forEach(schools, (s: any) => {
      const schoolDocumentData: OnboardingSchoolModel = s.payload.doc.data();
      const id: string = s.payload.doc.id;
      const school: OnboardingSchoolModel = {

        level: this.getIndexForLevel(schoolDocumentData.level),

      };
      schoolList.push(school);
    });
    resolve(schoolList);
  }, err => console.log(err));
});
```

}

```
getIndexForLevel(levelString: string): number {
    let levelIndex: number;
    switch (levelString) {
      case LevelEnum.High_School:
        levelIndex = 0;
        break;
      case LevelEnum.College:
        levelIndex = 1;
        break;
      case LevelEnum.Graduate:
        levelIndex = 2;
        break;
      default:
    }
    return levelIndex;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple type signatures for members, Union Types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006045/multiple-type-signatures-for-members-union-types-in-typescript)

Comment: No. If it works then why above error? @BaselIssmail

Comment: Your code looks correct to me and the thing that you are trying to achieve is called Union types and should work. Could you please provide more of your code, the way how and in what case you use your interface

Comment: @JSEvgeny I have updated. Please see it.

Comment: The problem is not with your interface, but with function that accepts string as an argument `getIndexForLevel(levelString: string)`. One possible solution (may be not the best one) could be changing `getIndexForLevel(levelString: string)` to accept union type `getIndexForLevel(levelString: string | number)`

Comment: I think this is the best solution. It works. Thanks. @JSEvgeny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***OP's Feedback***

This works great for me. i.e. `getIndexForLevel(levelString: string | number)`

```
  getIndexForLevel(levelString: string | number): number {
    let levelIndex: number;
    switch (levelString) {
      case LevelEnum.High_School:
        levelIndex = 0;
        break;
      case LevelEnum.College:
        levelIndex = 1;
        break;
      case LevelEnum.Graduate:
        levelIndex = 2;
        break;
      default:
    }
    return levelIndex;
  }
```

**Original Answer:**

Your function getIndexForLevel() take a string as argument but You give it string or number, force it as string.

```
level: this.getIndexForLevel(schoolDocumentData.level as string),
```

Comment: Any clue about how to do that for my use case above?

Comment: Edited my answer, can you try ?

Comment: @Sampath or change the function argument to be union type the same way as you did in interface